# Undefined Index Error in Wordpress

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code in Wordpress, with undefined index error for `$option_name`.  The options are saving correctly but I'm getting the error.

I have it wrapped with `isset` so I'm not understanding the problem.

```
if (isset ($_POST['update_theme_options'])) {

  $option_name_array = array_keys($slider_options);

  foreach ($option_name_array as $option_name):
    if(isset($slider_options[$option_name])):
      $slider_options[$option_name] = $_POST[$option_name];   
    endif;
  endforeach;

  update_option('slider_settings', $slider_options);
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the wrong array with `isset`. `$slider_options[$option_name]` will always exist, since `$option_name` came from `array_keys($slider_options)`. I think you meant to do:

```
if (isset($_POST[$option_name])):
```

The full code should be:

```
if (isset ($_POST['update_theme_options'])) {

  $option_name_array = array_keys($slider_options);

  foreach ($option_name_array as $option_name):
    if (isset($_POST[$option_name])):
      $slider_options[$option_name] = $_POST[$option_name];   
    endif;
  endforeach;

  update_option('slider_settings', $slider_options);
}
```

Comment: can you post final code to make sure I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: nevemind - it's fixed.  But you might still post final code :)